# Is DFT+U an ab initio based method?

Tags: density-functional-theory, dft-u

As the title already states is DFT+U considered an ab initio method?

Comment: Yes, DFT+U is an ab initio method. Nowadays, many DFT codes can calculate the Hubbard $U$ value **self-consistently**.

Comment: The answer is, it depends. If you want a pedantic response, in some very strict sense, these calculation might not get considered ab initio. The pseudopotentials might be generated using some empirical parameters, the U values are usually taken from literature (fine tuned from empirical results), etc. and these can harm the true ab initio nature of your calculation. But in a regular sense, where the U value(s) are taken self-consistently from linear response, cRPA, ACBN0 or other ab initio ways, the DFT+U calculation are usually considered as an ab initio calculation.

Comment: Related: https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/q/518/5, and https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/33764/27342

Comment: Thank you all, for answering my question :)

Comment: Even if the question is solved, I would like to add a comment: any theory that aims to calculate the properties of materials without needing the eigenvalues or eigenstates of another theory should be considered as ab initio. Density functional theory itself as a theory is free from experimental data and is clearly ab initio, although the application might be considered non ab initio. The Hubbard correction $U$ is also ab initio and can be calculated without any other experimental data or theory. Thus, DFT+$U$ is ab initio.